# Best way to store XML needed for api calls in a Python Package

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-requests, setuptools, python-packaging

I have a question about where to store XML data needed for making API calls in a python package I am building. For some of the API calls in my package I need to provide a binary xml string in the request. Right now I am reading it in from the same directory that my source code is kept in. What would be the best way to store this XML for use during run time after my project has been packaged and installed through pip? I read about `package_data` from the setuptools package but i'm not sure how you would open the files included in there when a API call is made.

Below is an example of how I am currently executing one of these API calls. and current directory structure.

```
def make_api_call(self):

    # line below just extracts creds for api call from db
    API_CREDENTIALS = self.stage_request()

    #request_input.xml contains xml needed to make request
    data = open('./request_input.xml', 'rb').read()
    r = requests.post(url='apiurl',data=data,auth=(API_CREDENTIALS[0], API_CREDENTIALS[1]),headers={'Content-Type': 'text/xml'})
```

```
-----Package
-------Packages
---------module1.py
---------module2.py
---------module3.py
---------request_input.xml
-----setup.py
-----README.md
```

Answer (score 0):

To read the package data, use one of the following...

- [`importlib.resources`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources)
- [`pkgutil.get_data()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data)
- [`pkg_resources` from *setuptools*](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pkg_resources.html#basic-resource-access)